# Как поменять libinput на evdev

Tags: linux, мышь

С драйвером ввода libinput невозможно попадать по кнопкам.

Параметр `libinput Accel Speed (331):   -1.000000` не особо спасает. Все равно поведение мыши неестественное.

Когда был evdev, там можно было изменить параметр `Device Accel Constant Deceleration` и выставить нужное значение, чем больше значение, тем медленее мышь, и простор практически безграничный, думаю, максимальне значение ограничивалось всем диапазоном int. В libinput такого нет.

[Вики Арча по Mouse acceleration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Mouse_acceleration) не помогло.

Теперь, что я пробовал: `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` менял драйвер на evdev в параметре драйвер, не помогло.

Потом, устанавливал `xserver-xorg-input-evdev` не помогло.

Также советовали удалить libinput после его установки, удалил, отвалилась клава и мышь, переустановил систему заново.

Comment: что за мыш? модель, что в dmesg при подключении?

Comment: Мышь Logitech модель так не скажу это нужно коробку от неё искать. Но она очень скоростная и дополнительных кнопок для переключения скорости у неё нету.

Comment: Что в dmesg не скажу. т.к. Психанул и поставил обратно винду. Может через пару дней когда нервы успокоятся снова попробую разобраться с этой проблемой.

Comment: И кстати у меня получилось установить evdev но параметр Device Accel Constant Deceleration который мне так нужен не работает

Answer (score 0):

> libinput Accel Speed (331):   -1.000000

Нужно выставлять значение 0.3 для того чтоб она работала в 3.33 раза медленней. 0..1 - замедление, 1..100 и больше - ускорение.

`0.0001` - ускорение будет не заметно, 0 - усорения вообще нет.

`-1` - при резком движении мышка улетает незначительно, при медленном - начинает ускоряться

На самой мышке часто бывает кнопка изменения скорости.

Comment: У меня стояло значение -1 да скорость нормальная но не в том суть. Само поведение мыши не такое как при evdev. Я на старом дистрибутиве с evdev ставил Device Accel Constant Deceleration 3.735 это идеальный параметр был для меня. т.к. На длинных дистанциях она быстрая а на мелких обьектах медленная а с libinput она всегда одинаковая

Answer (score 0):

В общем, все таки я нашел способ, как успешно сменить драйвер `libinput` на драйвер `evdev` и что бы работал `Device Accel Constant Deceleration`

1. Устанавливаем `xserver-xorg-input-evdev`
2. Переходим в `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` и ищем там файл `40-libinput.conf`
   , делаем копию на всякий случай.
3. Открываем файл `40-libinput.conf` Везде где написано в поле Driver пишем evdev, повторюсь везде, даже для клавиатуры. `Driver "evdev"`, больше ничего менять там ненужно.
4. Далее идем в `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` ищем там файл `30-touchpad-libinput.conf` и в поле Driver, меняем на evdev `Driver "evdev"`

Всё, перезагружаемся и можем менять параметр `Device Accel Constant Deceleration` на любое значение.

P.S. Только сейчас обнаружил одну неприятную особенность: В GUI в настройках мыши должны быть **не пустые** значения иначе работать не будет. Я не знаю почему. Я выставил:

1. Первый параметр "Ускорение" в значение: 2,0
2. Второй параметр "Чувствительность" в значение: 4px

И потом регулировал параметр `Device Accel Constant Deceleration` на свое усмотрение, подбирал оптимальное для меня значение.